# bootstrap datetime picker dynamic disabledHours not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm working on a Bootstrap DateTime picker to dynamically disable hours based on the result of an ajax request.

I use PHP Laravel to make an ajax request and get the `hours` array that should be disabled in the DateTime picker, this works fine and I'm getting the `array` of hours.

The problem is, the DateTime picker is not disabling the `hours` if I dynamically do it, but if I manually add the array of `hours`, it is working.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="weekday" id="weekday" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5">Friday</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="time_picker" class="lesson-timepicker" required>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<script>
    let weekday = document.getElementById('weekday')

    function filterTime() {
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'link-to-get-hours',
            data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, weekday: weekday.value},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == true) {
                    // data.time return for example is ['6'] or ['6', '7']
                    // here I'm loading the datetime picker and passed the array of hours
                    loadPicker(data.time)
                } else {
                    console.log(data.message)
                }
            },error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var r = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
                console.log(r.message)
            }
        });

        moment.updateLocale('en', {
            week: { dow: 1 } // Monday is the first day of the week
        })
    }

    function loadPicker(timeData) {
        console.log(timeData) // this is getting the passed array of hours, but still not working

        $('.lesson-timepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'hh:mm A',
            stepping: 30,
            disabledHours: timeData, // here I assigned the timeData array to disable the hours, but don't work
            // but it's working if I hard coded the array just like this: `disabledHours: ['6'],`
            icons: {
                up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
                down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
                previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                next: 'fa fa-chevron-right'
            }
        })
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', filterTime)
    weekday.onchange = filterTime
</script>
```

This code generates the array of hours using Laravel collections.

```
$schedules = Schedule::select('start_time', 'end_time')->approved()->whereBelongsTo($user)->where('weekday', $request->input('weekday'))->get()->toArray();

$scheduleCollection = collect($schedules)->map(function ($time) {
    return [date("g", strtotime($time['start_time'])), date("g", strtotime($time['end_time']))];
})->flatten();

$timeData = $scheduleCollection->values();

return response()->json([
    'status' => true,
    'time' => $timeData,
], 200);

// dd result of $timeData
#items: array:2 [
    0 => "6"
    1 => "7"
]
```

Screenshot from this line `console.log(timeData)`

[image]

Comment: could you add a screenshot of `console.log(timeData)` from the dev-tools

Comment: yes, wait a second.

Comment: make sure that you return array of numbers not strings

Comment: Is there any error in dev-tools?

Comment: @Joseph , no error in my console/dev-tools. I also tried this `disabledHours: ['6', '7'],` and it's working the same with integers.

Comment: let me test it on my device, give me a moment

Comment: @Joseph , I think I have a problem on my backend? as seen in the screenshot, probably the index in the array is the problem? I tried returning plain array like `['6', '7']` and it's working, but with the code I have in my backend, it's still not working.

Comment: I will update my question to include the backend code that is generating the array of hours.

Comment: After testing it works for me it looks that you have a problem with the backend code

Comment: @Joseph , yeah, I think so, just updated my question and added the backend code that generate the array of hours.

Comment: try to add `->toArray()` and `->flatMap()` instead of `flat()`

Comment: @Joseph , this one solve the issue, I add `->all()` at the end of the `->values()`. Updated code will be `$timeData = $scheduleCollection->values()->all();`

Comment: There's another problem, I am initializing two datetime pickers, one for the 'with' disabled hours, and one for the normal picker 'without' disabled hours. The other one is not initializing. I think we need to destroy the picker after changing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248993/discussion-between-lucky-person-and-joseph).

Comment: I got it, have to add this line `$('.lesson-timepicker').data('DateTimePicker').destroy()`